# Identifying duplicates in specific CSV output

Tags: ruby, arrays, parsing, csv

Ruby newbie here. I've got a product csv where first col is a unique SKU and second col is a product ID that can be duplicated across multiple products (+ many other cols but these are the pertinent ones). Like:

```
SKU     | Prod ID
 99     | 10384
100     | 10385
101     | 10385
102     | 10386
103     | 10386
104     | 10387
```

In the script I'm writing, the first time a product ID is used will become a 'parent', and any subsequent instances of the product ID get treated differently (ie, different sizes).

Currently am reading in the whole CSV rather than doing foreach line as I assumed I'd need all the data available to find the duplicates.

Issue is I'm not sure on the how to be able to identify the first time a product ID is used and then identifying any further instances of it's use.

My first thought was to somehow identify the duplicates (uniq?) and then create a new column and put a 1 if it's the first time it's occurred and 0 if it's occurred previously. After looking at uniq I'm not sure how I then go back to the main list and mark my 1's and 0's.

Can someone please point me in the direction of the classes/methods I need to be looking at?

Thanks,
Liam

Edit for John D: This gives me the hashes but in 1:1 format not 1: all instances of prod ID

```
CSV.foreach(INPUT, :headers => true , :header_converters => :symbol, :col_sep => "|",     :quote_char => "\x00") do |csv_obj|
  items[csv_obj.fields[0]] = [csv_obj.fields[1]]
end
```

so gives;
"230709"=>["88507"], "109064"=>["9019"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking of the `Sku` as the unique identifier, which it may in fact be.  But if you turn that on it's head and think of the `ProductID` as the unique identifier, then you can build a `Hash` where the key is the `ProductID` and the value is an `Array` of `Sku`s.  Then you'll be able to track which `Sku`s are associated with which `ProductID`.

Of course you'll read this in some other way, but the end result would be similar to:

```
products = 
{
  10384 => [99],
  10385 => [100, 101],
  10386 => [102, 103],
  10387 => [104]
}
```

Here's an example of how to construct this Hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'csv'

source = [
  "99|110384",
  "100|10385",
  "101|10385",
  "102|10386",
  "103|10386",
  "104|10387"
].join("\n")

source = CSV.parse(source, :col_sep => "|")

hh = source.inject({}) do |memo, row|
  sku = row[0]
  prod = row[1]

  memo[prod] = [] unless memo.include?(prod) 
  memo[prod] << sku
  memo
end

puts hh
```

Comment: Thanks John, I'm able to create the hash/array structure but I can't get my head around how to merge the duplicates?

Comment: Thanks John, the dbl parameter block on the do was new to me, as was inject and include?

Answer (score 2):

`.group_by()` is relatively new (though it has an older counterpart in Rails), but is awfully convenient and should do most of your heavy lifting.

If you create a class to hold each row and put them in an `Array`, then you can call the `group_by` method with a block that just checks each object's Product ID field.

That gives you a `Hash`, which you can iterate through with `.keys.each`.

Assuming a whole bunch of things about your program that are hopefully semi-obvious, something like:

```
transactionHash = transactions.group_by { |x| x.productId }
```

Then, you can go through your transaction lists per product with:

```
transactionHash.each do |prodId,transList|
  # transList has all of your transaction objects per product
end
```

Again, that assumes you're keeping your transactions in a list of objects.  The `x.productId` would be something like `x[1]` if you store each transaction in an array, for example.

Comment: Thanks John C; Just trying to work out how the terminology fits. I've got an array of arrays from reading in the csv, but can't get my head around how I call group by on the detailed row array inside the array holding the csv's data.

Comment: I avoided specifics, since I didn't want to assume the wrong structure for your data and mislead you, but I've added what I think is generic enough to use.  The key is that `group_by` just takes an expression that explains what defines the groupings.

Comment: Thanks John C; this helped me a lot as well; ie I refactored my existing code to use a class, feed it in then use group by; where previously I'd just been dealing with raw array's stuffed into variables.